# A small doubt in group rings.

Tags: ring-theory, group-rings

Let RG be a group ring then if $r \in R$ and $g \in G $ then why $rg=gr$ in RG?

What does the author means here. Why does these embeddings implies $rg=gr$

[image]

Comment: I guess it depends on what you wish to get. Given a nontrivial group-homomorphism $\phi\ :\ G\rightarrow \text{Aut}(R)$, one may also define a skew structure $gr=\phi_g(r)g$ and it would still induce a ring $H$. 
The definition I found, though, requires $R$ to commute with $G$. This ensure, as example, that a group ring over a commutative ring $R$ is a $R$-algebra.

Comment: The embedding of $G$ into $RG$ ensures that it makes sense to even consider
$rg$ and $gr$ as products of elements in $RG$. The equation $rg=gr$ should
then follow from the definition of the multiplication in $RG$ which the
author must have given earlier in that text.

Comment: What Marc's saying is right: the definition of (the usual) group algebra requires the scalars to commute with the group elements. This is changed in skew grouprings.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the author used the standard defnition
$$\left(\sum_{g\in G}a_gg\right)\left(\sum_{g\in G}b_gg\right):=\sum_{g\in G}\left[\left(\sum_{h\in G}a_hb_{h^{-1}g}\right)g\right]$$
From which it follows that $R=R\cdot e$ commutes with $G=1\cdot G$ through the identification he stated.

Actually, one may say that the multiplication above is the one and only making those identification commute between each other.